# Porque não consigo utilizar operador de adição em função com this?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, this, ecmascript-6

Por que quando eu rodo o seguinte código:

```
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;
    console.log(this.idade);
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.idade++;
          console.log(this.idade);
    }, 2000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

A minha saída é

```
0
NaN
```

E quando eu altero a atribuição feita dentro da função `setTimeout()` para:

```
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;
    console.log(this.idade);
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.idade = 1;
          console.log(this.idade);
    }, 2000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

A minha saída é:

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `this` na função dentro do setTimeout não faz mais referência a Pessoa e sim a função anônima que você definiu.

Você tem duas alternativas para esse cenário:

1 - Salvar a referência do `this` para `Pessoa` dentro de uma variável, para que então você possa acessar com essa variável a referência para pessoa.

```js
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;
    console.log(this.idade);

    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        _this.idade++;
          console.log(_this.idade);
    }, 2000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

2 - Utilizar [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Com arrow functions você consegue manter a referência do `this` na função externa.

```js
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;
    console.log(this.idade);

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.idade++;
          console.log(this.idade);
    }, 2000);
}

new Pessoa();
```